# How to calculate average number of zero crossings for a binary random walk of N steps when N is very large

Tags: combinatorics, random-walk

I know that $\frac{1}{2}(-1+2^{-n}(n+1)$$n \choose k$), where k = $\frac{n+1}{2}$, is the formula for calculating this, and I know that $n \choose k$ means $\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$, but  calculating $\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ for very large values of $n$ is time consuming, particularly when the results are too big for the computer's floating point processor to handle, in which case you have to use a special floating point library to deal with it.

I have written a program to solve this, and I made the code that solves $\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ to do a minimum number of multiplications. It takes about 15 seconds to give the solution for $n = 1000001$ as $398.4425796$, and because I wrote the 'very big number' handing routines myself, I'm not 100% sure my answer is correct to the number of decimal places I have given. Is there an elegant way to do this calculation a lot faster and preferably one that doesn't produce intermediate calculations that the computer's fp processor can't handle?

Comment: Large factorials and their products/quotients can be handled via the $lngamma$ function, which (sometimes under other names) calculates the natural log of the gamma function. As you might expect, it can allow for more range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Stirling’s series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation#Speed_of_convergence_and_error_estimates) to approximate the factorials. For the precision you’re after, you should include the $\frac1n$ term to be on the safe side:

$$\log n!=n(\log n-1)+\frac12\log(2\pi n)+\frac1{12n}+O\left(\frac1{n^3}\right)\;.$$

This yields

\begin{eqnarray}
\log\binom n{\frac{n+1}2}&\approx&n(\log n-1)+\frac12\log(2\pi n)+\frac1{12n}\\&&-\left(\left(\frac{n+1}2\right)\left(\log\left(\frac{n+1}2\right)-1\right)+\frac12\log\left(2\pi\frac{n+1}2\right)+\frac1{12\left(\frac{n+1}2\right)}\right)
\\&&-\left(\left(\frac{n-1}2\right)\left(\log\left(\frac{n-1}2\right)-1\right)+\frac12\log\left(2\pi\frac{n-1}2\right)+\frac1{12\left(\frac{n-1}2\right)}\right)
\\
&=&
n\log2-\left(\frac{n+1}2\right)\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)
-\left(\frac{n-1}2\right)\log\left(1-\frac1n\right)
-\frac12\log(2\pi n)\\
&&+\log2-\frac12\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)-\frac12\log\left(1-\frac1n\right)+\frac1{12}\left(\frac1n-\frac2{n+1}-\frac2{n-1}\right)
\\
&\approx&
(n+1)\log2-\frac{n+1}2\left(\frac1n-\frac1{2n^2}\right)+\frac{n-1}2\left(\frac1n+\frac1{2n^2}\right)-\frac12\log(2\pi n)-\frac1{4n}
\\
&\approx&
(n+1)\log2-\frac12\log(2\pi n)-\frac3{4n}\;.
\end{eqnarray}

Together with the rest of your formula (except for the $-\frac12$), this yields the approximation

$$-(n+1)\log2+\log(n+1)+(n+1)\log2-\frac12\log(2\pi n)-\frac3{4n}\approx\bbox[5px, border: 1px solid green]{\frac12\log\frac n{2\pi}+\frac1{4n}}$$

for the logarithm of the expected number of zero crossings. For $n=1000001$, this is

$$
\frac12\log\frac{1000001}{2\pi}+\frac1{4\cdot1000001}\approx5.988817495776964\;,
$$

corresponding to an expected number of approximately

$$
398.44257960805571
$$

zero crossings (now with $-\frac12$ included), in agreement with your result. This agrees in all digits with [the value produced by Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-1%2F2%2B2%5E(-(n%2B1))%20*%20(n%2B1)%20*%20binom%20(n%2C(n%2B1)%2F2)%20where%20n%3D1000001&dataset=). I thought I discarded terms of order $\frac1{n^2}$, but this seems to be accurate up to that order, so either Wolfram|Alpha also only uses an expansion up to order $\frac1n$ for that calculation, or the discarded terms of order $\frac1{n^2}$ cancel out. Wolfram|Alpha also [returns the above approximation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=series%20for%20-1%2F2%20%2B%20log%20%282%5E%28-%28n%2B1%29%29%20%28n%2B1%29%20gamma%28n%2B1%29%20%2F%20%28gamma%20%28%28n%2B3%29%2F2%29%20gamma%20%28%28n%2B1%29%2F2%29%29%29%20at%20n%3Dinfinity) up to order $\frac1n$; unfortunately, clicking on “More terms” doesn’t actually produce more terms.

Comment: Thank you @joriki. I'll have to study your explanation, but it seems like your calculation produced a number which is almost exactly 0.5 higher than what I calculated. My calculation out to 15 significant digits was 398.442579608025. I just did my calculation for n=1,010,101 and the result was 400.452175140044. I wonder if your calculation would produce a number which is almost exactly 0.5 higher? And if so, then which result is correct? In either case, I would certainly want to use your method and just subtract 0.5 or not, whichever gives the right answer.

Comment: @BNB: Sorry – the $-\frac12$ term isn't included in the logarithm; I should have added it after exponentiation (and should have noticed that all your other digits were correct). I edited the answer accordingly. Well done to calculate to that accuracy with so many large multiplications!

Comment: It just occurred to me that if I dropped the -1 from my equation it would produce your result. I think I understand why you said "obviously dropping the -1" because my equation can be simplified as -0.5 +1/2*(the rest of it). So, I think maybe subtracting -0.5 from your equation does indeed give the right answer?  ..and, you already figured that out while I was writing this. Thanks a million!